# What's the origin of the term croustille for potato chips

Tags: usage, étymologie, québec

I've noticed that potato chips are translated as croustilles in Canada. This seems to be a Quebec French term (and the term pomme chips is used elsewhere)[(1)](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8365214)[(2)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chips)

I haven't been able to find where this usage of the term originates from. I'm guessing the word itself must come from croustiller, but I'm wondering when/how the term started being used specifically in the context of potato chips?

Any insight is appreciated, and since my French is very limited, please let me know if I made any incorrect assumptions!

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas ce terme, car en France on emploie malheureusement « chips » (prononcé : « ships » !), mais je le trouve très bon !

Comment: I am not from Quebec so it may be not entirely true, but Quebecois hate English words and will find or create a new word - so chips was out of question for naming these. In UK English, potato chips are called crisps (maybe for the sound they make when we eat them), so croustilles sounds like a good alternative.

Comment: The french word people use in France is also "tuiles". I read it often on packages and use it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Quebec, there is an organization responsible to translate and make the promotion of French terms instead of using english words, especially with neologisms, that is l'*Office québécois de la langue française*.

The translation was created by them (at the end of the seventies I would say) and they tried very hard to make this translation adopted by everyone in Quebec, but still, the word *chip*, for *potato chip*, is widely used in spoken French. Though, since it's the official translation, you will encounter the word croustilles on packages that are sold in French Canada.

Official Information here: http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8365214